# "No executable found matching command" .net core console application

Tags: .net-core

After publishing my .net core 2.0 console application...

`dotnet publish src\myapp.console --output C:\publish\console --configuration Release`

I try executing in this in the published folder

`dotnet myapp.console`

but I get the error

`No executable found matching command "dotnet-myapp.console"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to include the full file name with `.dll`

ie:
`dotnet myapp.console.dll`